# Why is my lens focusing sound lounder than before?

Tags: lens, autofocus, focus

I'm new to DSLR camera. I didn't mount a lens properly. The camera still allowed me to take photos, so I didn't notice the error.

After I had been using it for 10 minutes I noticed my error and mounted the lens properly.

The problem is the lens focusing sound is getting louder than before.

Is it dangerous to my lens? Should I send back to factory to fix?

Comment: You may well have damaged the lens or the body.  The fact that it sounds different after being mounted properly means something changed, which is unlikely to be good.  Does it seem fine with another lens?  If so, you probably only damaged the lens.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how you didn't mount it properly? It could be helpful both for appreciating possible outcomes and for other people who may have done the same error and will search the web.

Answer (score 3):

If the lens still works but just makes a louder noise, I would personally continue to use it, assuming that it is still functioning correctly(focus, image stabilization, etc). If you are still under a warranty I would certainly take advantage of that and send it in. But if I had to pay out of pocket to have it looked at I would rather wait until it didn't work at all then pay for something I might not have needed. This is all based on the assumption that you don't have a "very important" vacation or photography event that you are using the lens for. If you have no other backups take that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what the noise actually sounds like and how loud it is. If the lens was not mounted properly then there is likely to be a gap between it and the camera body which would allow dust in. If dust gets behind (and into) then lens then it might be causing the noise?

Also depending on what lens it is, maybe you have switched on the stabilization feature? This has a motor which makes (at least on my Nikkor) a much lounder sound than the focusing motor. When I got my first camera I didn't notice this sound at first until I started listening to the noises, that is why I'm making you aware of it.

Ultimately I doubt the lens was damaged from being improperly mounted in such a way that it would start making a noise that would get louder over time. Considering you are new to the camera my guess is that it is another aspect which you have not yet familiarized yourself with yet,